# Android New Activity Error

Tags: android, android-activity, oncreate

I currently have at least 5 Android Activity in my Android Project. I haven't experience any problems creating those activities. But when I add another activity, It shows an error on the "onCreateOptionsMenu" and "onCreate". Do you have any idea as to what I can do to solve this?

Comment: Post code where problem occurred.

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: Please always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"onCreateOptionsMenu" it is problem for "Menu". And be careful 5 new Activity for create 5 Activity in AndroidMenifest + Application.........